# Why my data is not updating?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I am trying to update ClientInfo table. But it is not updating and shows that Undefined. Those code below i have used in my controller for updating my database table data. Where is my problem i cannot find out? experts please help me..

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update(ClientInfo clnt, int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ClientInfo c = db.Query<ClientInfo>("Select * from ClientInfo Where CId=@0", id).First<ClientInfo>();
                c.CName = clnt.CName;
                c.CCName = clnt.CCName;
                c.Address = clnt.Address;
                c.PhoneNo = clnt.PhoneNo;
                c.Fax = clnt.Fax;
                c.Email = clnt.Email;
                c.Country = clnt.Country;
                c.PostalCode = clnt.PostalCode;
                c.Update();
                return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
                return Json(new { msg = "Fail to Update Client Info." + id });
        }
```

And Search Controller For searching Data

```
public JsonResult Search2(string id=null)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                var sresult = db.Query<ClientInfo>("Where CId=" + id).ToList<ClientInfo>();
                return Json(sresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

And my ajax call from views For searching data by cid value..

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CId').blur(function () {
            var v = $('#CId').val();
            var url = "/Clients/Search2/" + v;
          //  alert("Test : " + url);

            $("#CName").val("");
            $("#CCName").val("");
            $("#PhoneNo").val("");
            $("#Fax").val("");
            $("#Email").val("");
            $("#Address").val("");
            $("#PostalCode").val("");
            $("#Country").val("");

            $.getJSON(url, null, function (data, status) {
                $.each(data, function (index, C) {
                    $("#CName").val(C.CName);
                    $("#CCName").val(C.CCName);
                    $("#PhoneNo").val(C.PhoneNo);
                    $("#Fax").val(C.Fax);
                    $("#Email").val(C.Email);
                    $("#Address").val(C.Address);
                    $("#PostalCode").val(C.PostalCode);
                    $("#Country").val(C.Country);
                });
            });
        });
```

For database update  i have used this function ...

```
        $('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
            var CId = $("#CId").val();
            var CName = $("#CName").val();
            var CCName = $("#CCName").val();
            var PhoneNo = $("#PhoneNo").val();
            var Fax = $("#Fax").val();
            var Email = $("#Email").val();
            var Address = $("#Address").val();
            var PostalCode = $("#PostalCode").val();
            var Country = $("#Country").val();

            var client1 = {
                "CId": CId,
                "CName": CName,
                "CCName": CCName,
                "PhoneNo": PhoneNo,
                "Fax": Fax,
                "Email": Email,
                "Address": Address,
                "PostalCode": PostalCode,
                "Country": Country
            };

            var lk = "/Clients/Update/" + CId;

            //alert("Test : Update " + lk + "\n" + client1.Country);
            client = JSON.stringify(client1);

            $.ajax({
                cashe: false,
                async: false,
                url: lk,
                type: 'POST',
                data: client,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
}
```

Comment: Provide your c.Update() method definition.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan boss, I don't understand that what is c.update method definition. But i using micro orm petapoco, it gives me ready all cs file. I am just using those code in my project.

Comment: @MNAH Are you using the entity framework or your own data access layer implementation?

Comment: @Candide No, I am not using entity framework, i am using petapoco micro orm.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `Undefined` in your alert message box, it's simple:

```
$.ajax({
    cashe: false,
    async: false,
    url: lk,
    type: 'POST',
    data: client,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.msg);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.msg);
    }
});
```

Your ajax code displays the content of `data.msg`. But when your model is valid, it retrieves the model from the database, updates it and returns the new model. There is no `msg` json property if it succeeds, hence `data.msg` is undefined.

If you want it to return a success message, you need to change

```
return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

into

```
return Json(new { msg = "Update Successful.",  record = c }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

then you will have a message in `data.msg` and your newly updated record in `data.record`.

Comment: Then post your Firebug output/json string that is return from the server.

Answer (score 0):

DBContext have a save method you must run this.

Did you run Save(); method ?

Comment: in create method i have used this save(); this code is
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ClientInfo ci)
        {
            ClientInfo cil = new ClientInfo();
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    ci.Save();
                    
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(cil);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }